# What's the difference between type1 -> type2 -> type3 and type1 -> (type2 -> type3)?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

Why

```
let f1 a b = a + b
```

and

```
let f2 a = fun b -> a + b
```

both produce values with type `a:int -> b:int -> int`,

 but

```
let f3 a =
   let f = 
     fun b -> a + b 
   f
```

and

```
let f4 a =
   let f b = a + b
   f
```

both produce values with type `a:int -> (int -> int)` ? 
What do braces around `int -> int` mean?
Are there situations where these two types do different things in a program?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no difference, `type1 -> type2 -> type3` is just syntactic sugar for `type1 -> (type2 -> type3)`

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/

> The answer is quite simple: a function with multiple parameters is rewritten as a series of new functions, each with only one parameter. And this is done automatically by the compiler for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like mclark1129 says, there's no difference; you can read it as either a function of two arguments or two functions of a single argument – the brackets here denote a function because if you supply only the first argument (`type1`) the function will return a function that takes a `type2` and returns a `type3`.

Currying and partial application are foundational to functional programming and underpin things like algebraic data structures where currying/partially applying multi-arity functions down to single argument functions are the norm.